# ARM Cortex M33: tiny error when using MAC instruction (UMLAL)

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

I'm implementing a cryptographic library, which has optimized assembly for ARM Cortex M-0 architecture, including several units using multiply-accumulate macro, which uses 32x32->32 bit multiplications.

I'm using M-33 which supports 32x32-->64 multiplication. So I first optimized the algorithms by replacing the 32-bit multiplications (and some additions) with 64-bit variant (UMULL), which worked correctly. However, the Cortex M33 also supports single instruction for 64-bit MAC (UMLAL). When I used this instruction, the results was correct except 2 bits : 0xe5c528f**b**, 0xc5abc3f**c** (11th and 12th values).

The wrong result by using UMLAL:

```
   umlal_result = 
  {0xb45deb28, 0xeb23a781, 0xec09b357, 0xe561f5f5, 0x1e3fa5d2, 0x828ad2db, 
   0x60c67a8a, 0xd2850733, 0xad1de690, 0x6e1ceba1, 0xe5c528fb, 0xc5abc3fc, 
   0x2f648d3b, 0xe13039aa, 0x58cc1ff4, 0x1d7521f1}
```

The right one (UMULL):

```
  umull_result = 
  {0xb45deb28, 0xeb23a781, 0xec09b357, 0xe561f5f5, 0x1e3fa5d2, 0x828ad2db, 
   0x60c67a8a, 0xd2850733, 0xad1de690, 0x6e1ceba1, 0xe5c528fc, 0xc5abc3fb, 
   0x2f648d3b, 0xe13039aa, 0x58cc1ff4, 0x1d7521f1}
```

I tried to debug through the problem, but couldn't find the reason. So my question is, what could be the problem? In my opinion, the two samples above are equivalent, affecting the same flags.. Apparently that is not the case. My guess would be that all the modifications would need to locate in mulacc macro, as it simply takes 2*32 bit inputs and outputs 64 bits as the result of MAC, and of course, updates the required flags. All the numbers I'm using are unsigned.

Any advice will be appreciated.

EDIT2: A test-code containing all the necessary: .S files for both umlal, umull versions and a main function for calling them.

The karatsuba_umull.S file:

```
.macro mulacc
 @fixed: 64-bit multiply for Cortex M-33
    umull r6, r0, r1, r2

    mov r7, #0
    add r5, r5, r6
    adc r4, r4, r0
    adc r3, r3, r7
.endm

.macro loadAndAdd reg, idx
.if \reg == sp || \reg == r0
   ldr r6, [\reg, #\idx*4]
.else
   mov r0, \reg
   ldr r6, [r0, #\idx*4]
.endif
   add r5, r5, r6
   adc r4, r4, r7
.endm

.macro loadAndSub reg, idx
.if \reg == sp || \reg == r0
   ldr r6, [\reg, #\idx*4]
.else
   mov r0, \reg
   ldr r6, [r0, #\idx*4]
.endif
   sub r5, r5, r6
   sbc r4, r4, r7
.endm

.macro loadAndAddIfCarry carryReg, opReg, idx
   ldr r0, [\opReg, #\idx*4]
   mov r1, \carryReg
   and r0, r0, r1
   add r5, r5, r0 @ tässä pitäisi olla 1? umuls mid kohta 7
   adc r4, r4, r7
.endm

.macro loadMultiply regA, regB, idxA, idxB
.if \regA == sp
   ldr r1, [sp, #\idxA*4]
.else
   mov r1, \regA
   ldr r1, [r1, #\idxA*4]
.endif
.if \regB == sp
   ldr r2, [sp, #\idxB*4]
.else
   mov r2, \regB
   ldr r2, [r2, #\idxB*4]
.endif
   mulacc
.endm

.macro storeAndShiftAcc regDst, idx
.if \regDst == sp || \regDst == r0
   str r5, [\regDst, #\idx*4]
.else
   mov r6, \regDst
   str r5, [r6, #\idx*4]
.endif
   mov r5, r4
   mov r4, r3
   asr r3, r4, #32
.endm

.macro storeRemAcc regDst, idx1, idx2
.if \regDst == sp
   str r5, [sp, #\idx1*4]
   str r4, [sp, #\idx2*4]
.else
   mov r6, \regDst
   str r5, [r6, #\idx1*4]
   str r4, [r6, #\idx2*4]
.endif
.endm

.macro resetAccumulator
   ldr r3, =0
   mov r4, r3
   mov r5, r3
.endm

.macro multiplyLow
   loadMultiply r8,r9,0,0
   storeAndShiftAcc r10, 0

   loadMultiply r9,r8,1,0
   loadMultiply r9,r8,0,1
   storeAndShiftAcc r10, 1

   loadMultiply r8,r9,2,0
   loadMultiply r8,r9,1,1
   loadMultiply r8,r9,0,2
   storeAndShiftAcc r10, 2

   loadMultiply r9,r8,3,0
   loadMultiply r8,r9,1,2
   loadMultiply r8,r9,2,1
   loadMultiply r8,r9,3,0
   storeAndShiftAcc r10, 3

   loadMultiply r9,r8,1,3
   loadMultiply r9,r8,2,2
   loadMultiply r9,r8,3,1
   storeAndShiftAcc sp, 8

   loadMultiply r8,r9,2,3
   loadMultiply r8,r9,3,2
   storeAndShiftAcc sp, 9

   loadMultiply r9,r8,3,3
   storeRemAcc sp, 10, 11
.endm

.macro multiplyHigh
   loadMultiply r8,r9,4,4
   storeAndShiftAcc r10, 8

   loadMultiply r9,r8,5,4
   loadMultiply r9,r8,4,5
   storeAndShiftAcc r10, 9

   loadMultiply r8,r9,6,4
   loadMultiply r8,r9,5,5
   loadMultiply r8,r9,4,6
   storeAndShiftAcc r10, 10

   loadMultiply r9,r8,7,4
   loadMultiply r8,r9,5,6
   loadMultiply r8,r9,6,5
   loadMultiply r8,r9,7,4
   storeAndShiftAcc r10, 11

   loadMultiply r9,r8,5,7
   loadMultiply r9,r8,6,6
   loadMultiply r9,r8,7,5
   storeAndShiftAcc r10, 12

   loadMultiply r8,r9,6,7
   loadMultiply r8,r9,7,6
   storeAndShiftAcc r10, 13

   loadMultiply r9,r8,7,7
   storeRemAcc r10, 14, 15
.endm

.macro multiplyMiddle
   mov r7, #0
   mov r0, r10
   loadAndAdd sp, 8
   loadAndSub r0,8
   loadAndSub r0,0
   asr r3, r4, #32
   loadMultiply sp,sp,0,4
   storeAndShiftAcc r10,4

   mov r0, r10
   loadAndAdd sp, 9
   loadAndSub r0,9
   loadAndSub r0,1
   asr r3, r4, #32
   loadMultiply sp,sp,1,4
   loadMultiply sp,sp,0,5
   storeAndShiftAcc r10,5

   mov r0, r10
   loadAndAdd sp, 10
   loadAndSub r0,10
   loadAndSub r0,2
   asr r3, r4, #32
   loadMultiply sp,sp,2,4
   loadMultiply sp,sp,1,5
   loadMultiply sp,sp,0,6
   storeAndShiftAcc r10,6

   mov r0, r10
   loadAndAdd sp, 11
   loadAndSub r0,11
   loadAndSub r0,3
   asr r3, r4, #32
   loadMultiply sp,sp,3,4
   loadMultiply sp,sp,2,5
   loadMultiply sp,sp,1,6
   loadMultiply sp,sp,0,7
   storeAndShiftAcc r10,7

   loadAndAddIfCarry  r11, sp, 4
   loadAndAddIfCarry r12, sp, 0
   mov r0, r10
   loadAndAdd r0,8
   loadAndSub r0,12
   loadAndSub sp,8
   asr r3, r4, #32
   loadMultiply sp,sp,3,5
   loadMultiply sp,sp,2,6
   loadMultiply sp,sp,1,7
   storeAndShiftAcc r10,8

   loadAndAddIfCarry  r11, sp, 5
   loadAndAddIfCarry r12, sp, 1
   mov r0, r10
   loadAndAdd r0,9
   loadAndSub r0,13
   loadAndSub sp,9
   asr r3, r4, #32
   loadMultiply sp,sp,3,6
   loadMultiply sp,sp,2,7
   storeAndShiftAcc r10,9

   loadAndAddIfCarry  r11, sp, 6
   loadAndAddIfCarry r12, sp, 2 @ r4 = 1 with umuls
   mov r0, r10
   loadAndAdd r0,10
   loadAndSub r0,14
   loadAndSub sp,10
   asr r3, r4, #32
   loadMultiply sp,sp,3,7
   storeAndShiftAcc r10,10

   loadAndAddIfCarry  r11, sp, 7
   loadAndAddIfCarry r12, sp, 3
   mov r0, r10
   loadAndAdd r0,11
   loadAndSub r0,15
   loadAndSub sp,11
   asr r3, r4, #32
   storeAndShiftAcc r0,11

   addCarries
   loadRegAndAdd r1,12
   str r5, [r1, #12*4]
   mov r5, r4
   loadRegAndAddNoAcc r1,13
   str r5, [r1, #13*4]
   loadRegAndAddCarry r1,14
   str r5, [r1, #14*4]
   loadRegAndAddCarry r1,15
   str r5, [r1, #15*4]
.endm

.macro loadRegAndAddCarry baseReg, idx
   ldr r5, [\baseReg, #\idx*4]
   adc r5, r5, r7
.endm

.macro loadRegAndAddNoAcc baseReg, idx
   ldr r6, [\baseReg, #\idx*4]
   add r5, r5, r6
.endm

.macro loadRegAndAdd baseReg, idx
   ldr r6, [\baseReg, #\idx*4]
   add r5, r5, r6
   adc r4, r4, r7
.endm

.macro addCarries
   mov r6, r11
   mov r0, r12
   and r6, r6, r0
   neg r6, r6
   add r5, r5, r6
   adc r4, r4, r7
   mov r1, r10
.endm

.macro sumA
   @ to use: r3, r4, r5, r6, r7
   ldm r1, {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7}

   add r4, r4, r0
   adc r5, r5, r1
   adc r6, r6, r2
   adc r7, r7, r3

   sbc r3, r3, r3
   mvn r3, r3
   mov r11, r3

   mov r1, sp
   stm r1, {r4, r5, r6, r7}
.endm

.macro sumB
   @ to use: r3, r4, r5, r6, r7
   mov r1, r9
   ldm r1, {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7}

   add r4, r4, r0
   adc r5, r5, r1
   adc r6, r6, r2
   adc r7, r7, r3

   sbc r3, r3, r3
   mvn r3, r3
   mov r12, r3

   add r1, sp, #16
   stm r1, {r4, r5, r6, r7}
.endm

.global bi_multiply_cm0_umull
.type bi_multiply_cm0_umull, function
.text 1
.thumb

@ res:          r0
@ operand a:    r1
@ operand b:    r2
bi_multiply_cm0_umull:
   push {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
   mov r4, r8
   mov r5, r9
   mov r6, r10
   mov r7, r11
   push {r4, r5, r6, r7}
   mov r4, r12
   push {r4}

   sub sp, sp, #64

   mov r8, r1
   mov r9, r2
   mov r10, r0

   sumA
   sumB

   resetAccumulator

   multiplyLow

   resetAccumulator

   multiplyHigh

   resetAccumulator

   multiplyMiddle

   add sp, sp, #64

   pop {r4}
   mov r12, r4
   pop {r4, r5, r6, r7}
   mov r8, r4
   mov r9, r5
   mov r10, r6
   mov r11, r7
   pop {r4, r5, r6, r7, pc}
```

karatsuba_umlal.S file

```
.macro mulacc
@ fixed: 64-bit multiply for Cortex M-33
    umlal r5, r4, r1, r2

    mov r7, #0
    adc r3, r3, r7

.endm

.macro loadAndAdd reg, idx
.if \reg == sp || \reg == r0
   ldr r6, [\reg, #\idx*4]
.else
   mov r0, \reg
   ldr r6, [r0, #\idx*4]
.endif
   add r5, r5, r6
   adc r4, r4, r7
.endm

.macro loadAndSub reg, idx
.if \reg == sp || \reg == r0
   ldr r6, [\reg, #\idx*4]
.else
   mov r0, \reg
   ldr r6, [r0, #\idx*4]
.endif
   sub r5, r5, r6
   sbc r4, r4, r7
.endm

.macro loadAndAddIfCarry carryReg, opReg, idx
   ldr r0, [\opReg, #\idx*4]
   mov r1, \carryReg
   and r0, r0, r1
   add r5, r5, r0 @ tässä pitäisi olla 1? umuls mid kohta 7
   adc r4, r4, r7
.endm

.macro loadMultiply regA, regB, idxA, idxB
.if \regA == sp
   ldr r1, [sp, #\idxA*4]
.else
   mov r1, \regA
   ldr r1, [r1, #\idxA*4]
.endif
.if \regB == sp
   ldr r2, [sp, #\idxB*4]
.else
   mov r2, \regB
   ldr r2, [r2, #\idxB*4]
.endif
   mulacc
.endm

.macro storeAndShiftAcc regDst, idx
.if \regDst == sp || \regDst == r0
   str r5, [\regDst, #\idx*4]
.else
   mov r6, \regDst
   str r5, [r6, #\idx*4]
.endif
   mov r5, r4
   mov r4, r3
   asr r3, r4, #32
.endm

.macro storeRemAcc regDst, idx1, idx2
.if \regDst == sp
   str r5, [sp, #\idx1*4]
   str r4, [sp, #\idx2*4]
.else
   mov r6, \regDst
   str r5, [r6, #\idx1*4]
   str r4, [r6, #\idx2*4]
.endif
.endm

.macro resetAccumulator
   ldr r3, =0
   mov r4, r3
   mov r5, r3
.endm

.macro multiplyLow
   loadMultiply r8,r9,0,0
   storeAndShiftAcc r10, 0

   loadMultiply r9,r8,1,0
   loadMultiply r9,r8,0,1
   storeAndShiftAcc r10, 1

   loadMultiply r8,r9,2,0
   loadMultiply r8,r9,1,1
   loadMultiply r8,r9,0,2
   storeAndShiftAcc r10, 2

   loadMultiply r9,r8,3,0
   loadMultiply r8,r9,1,2
   loadMultiply r8,r9,2,1
   loadMultiply r8,r9,3,0
   storeAndShiftAcc r10, 3

   loadMultiply r9,r8,1,3
   loadMultiply r9,r8,2,2
   loadMultiply r9,r8,3,1
   storeAndShiftAcc sp, 8

   loadMultiply r8,r9,2,3
   loadMultiply r8,r9,3,2
   storeAndShiftAcc sp, 9

   loadMultiply r9,r8,3,3
   storeRemAcc sp, 10, 11
.endm

.macro multiplyHigh
   loadMultiply r8,r9,4,4
   storeAndShiftAcc r10, 8

   loadMultiply r9,r8,5,4
   loadMultiply r9,r8,4,5
   storeAndShiftAcc r10, 9

   loadMultiply r8,r9,6,4
   loadMultiply r8,r9,5,5
   loadMultiply r8,r9,4,6
   storeAndShiftAcc r10, 10

   loadMultiply r9,r8,7,4
   loadMultiply r8,r9,5,6
   loadMultiply r8,r9,6,5
   loadMultiply r8,r9,7,4
   storeAndShiftAcc r10, 11

   loadMultiply r9,r8,5,7
   loadMultiply r9,r8,6,6
   loadMultiply r9,r8,7,5
   storeAndShiftAcc r10, 12

   loadMultiply r8,r9,6,7
   loadMultiply r8,r9,7,6
   storeAndShiftAcc r10, 13

   loadMultiply r9,r8,7,7
   storeRemAcc r10, 14, 15
.endm

.macro multiplyMiddle
   mov r7, #0
   mov r0, r10
   loadAndAdd sp, 8
   loadAndSub r0,8
   loadAndSub r0,0
   asr r3, r4, #32
   loadMultiply sp,sp,0,4
   storeAndShiftAcc r10,4

   mov r0, r10
   loadAndAdd sp, 9
   loadAndSub r0,9
   loadAndSub r0,1
   asr r3, r4, #32
   loadMultiply sp,sp,1,4
   loadMultiply sp,sp,0,5
   storeAndShiftAcc r10,5

   mov r0, r10
   loadAndAdd sp, 10
   loadAndSub r0,10
   loadAndSub r0,2
   asr r3, r4, #32
   loadMultiply sp,sp,2,4
   loadMultiply sp,sp,1,5
   loadMultiply sp,sp,0,6
   storeAndShiftAcc r10,6

   mov r0, r10
   loadAndAdd sp, 11
   loadAndSub r0,11
   loadAndSub r0,3
   asr r3, r4, #32
   loadMultiply sp,sp,3,4
   loadMultiply sp,sp,2,5
   loadMultiply sp,sp,1,6
   loadMultiply sp,sp,0,7
   storeAndShiftAcc r10,7

   loadAndAddIfCarry  r11, sp, 4
   loadAndAddIfCarry r12, sp, 0
   mov r0, r10
   loadAndAdd r0,8
   loadAndSub r0,12
   loadAndSub sp,8
   asr r3, r4, #32
   loadMultiply sp,sp,3,5
   loadMultiply sp,sp,2,6
   loadMultiply sp,sp,1,7
   storeAndShiftAcc r10,8

   loadAndAddIfCarry  r11, sp, 5
   loadAndAddIfCarry r12, sp, 1
   mov r0, r10
   loadAndAdd r0,9
   loadAndSub r0,13
   loadAndSub sp,9
   asr r3, r4, #32
   loadMultiply sp,sp,3,6
   loadMultiply sp,sp,2,7
   storeAndShiftAcc r10,9

   loadAndAddIfCarry  r11, sp, 6
   loadAndAddIfCarry r12, sp, 2 @ r4 = 1 with umuls
   mov r0, r10
   loadAndAdd r0,10
   loadAndSub r0,14
   loadAndSub sp,10
   asr r3, r4, #32
   loadMultiply sp,sp,3,7
   storeAndShiftAcc r10,10

   loadAndAddIfCarry  r11, sp, 7
   loadAndAddIfCarry r12, sp, 3
   mov r0, r10
   loadAndAdd r0,11
   loadAndSub r0,15
   loadAndSub sp,11
   asr r3, r4, #32
   storeAndShiftAcc r0,11

   addCarries
   loadRegAndAdd r1,12
   str r5, [r1, #12*4]
   mov r5, r4
   loadRegAndAddNoAcc r1,13
   str r5, [r1, #13*4]
   loadRegAndAddCarry r1,14
   str r5, [r1, #14*4]
   loadRegAndAddCarry r1,15
   str r5, [r1, #15*4]
.endm

.macro loadRegAndAddCarry baseReg, idx
   ldr r5, [\baseReg, #\idx*4]
   adc r5, r5, r7
.endm

.macro loadRegAndAddNoAcc baseReg, idx
   ldr r6, [\baseReg, #\idx*4]
   add r5, r5, r6
.endm

.macro loadRegAndAdd baseReg, idx
   ldr r6, [\baseReg, #\idx*4]
   add r5, r5, r6
   adc r4, r4, r7
.endm

.macro addCarries
   mov r6, r11
   mov r0, r12
   and r6, r6, r0
   neg r6, r6
   add r5, r5, r6
   adc r4, r4, r7
   mov r1, r10
.endm

.macro sumA
   @ to use: r3, r4, r5, r6, r7
   ldm r1, {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7}

   add r4, r4, r0
   adc r5, r5, r1
   adc r6, r6, r2
   adc r7, r7, r3

   sbc r3, r3, r3
   mvn r3, r3
   mov r11, r3

   mov r1, sp
   stm r1, {r4, r5, r6, r7}
.endm

.macro sumB
   @ to use: r3, r4, r5, r6, r7
   mov r1, r9
   ldm r1, {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7}

   add r4, r4, r0
   adc r5, r5, r1
   adc r6, r6, r2
   adc r7, r7, r3

   sbc r3, r3, r3
   mvn r3, r3
   mov r12, r3

   add r1, sp, #16
   stm r1, {r4, r5, r6, r7}
.endm

.global bi_multiply_cm0_umlal
.type bi_multiply_cm0_umlal, function
.text 1
.thumb

@ res:          r0
@ operand a:    r1
@ operand b:    r2
bi_multiply_cm0_umlal:
   push {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
   mov r4, r8
   mov r5, r9
   mov r6, r10
   mov r7, r11
   push {r4, r5, r6, r7}
   mov r4, r12
   push {r4}

   sub sp, sp, #64

   mov r8, r1
   mov r9, r2
   mov r10, r0

   sumA
   sumB

   resetAccumulator

   multiplyLow

   resetAccumulator

   multiplyHigh

   resetAccumulator

   multiplyMiddle

   add sp, sp, #64

   pop {r4}
   mov r12, r4
   pop {r4, r5, r6, r7}
   mov r8, r4
   mov r9, r5
   mov r10, r6
   mov r11, r7
   pop {r4, r5, r6, r7, pc}
```

Minimal test function (mainfunc.c) for calling:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define FP_WORDS 8

typedef uint32_t word_t;
typedef word_t bigint_t[FP_WORDS];

static const bigint_t var_a = { 0x52766F6A, 0xACBDC62E, 0x32D23576,                 
0x600D522F, 0x19049F3B, 0xC4B0D05E, 0xC0FE0998, 0xB70E64D5 };

static const bigint_t var_b = { 0x8FE44968, 0xDEF5AF3C, 0x3D568ABD,             
0x09372473, 0x9AF4FFC7, 0x3A822C26, 0x522D6E14, 0x2DAAB214 };

void bi_multiply_cm0_umull(word_t res[2*FP_WORDS], bigint_t a, bigint_t b);
void bi_multiply_cm0_umlal(word_t res[2*FP_WORDS], bigint_t a, bigint_t b);

int main()
{
    word_t res_umull[2*FP_WORDS], res_umlal[2*FP_WORDS];
    bi_multiply_cm0_umull(res_umull, var_a, var_b);
    bi_multiply_cm0_umlal(res_umlal, var_a, var_b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please augment your question with a test vector, i.e. an example with the input values you are using and the two resulting values (one per method) you are getting ? this would help reproducing the problem.

Comment: Done. Added as in C test bench program.

Comment: @old_timer there was more errors in the last numbers of the 32-bit result array values. The carry was likely not added successfully.

Comment: @old_timer The .S file behind the link contains all the necessary; it is called directly with the listed values var_a, var_b and produces the result. But of course, it is quite difficult to say from just looking at that file. I try to do a bit more research / try to disassemble it as soon as I can.. Thanks for the comments

Comment: As quite beginner on the field I'm not really sure what could be the problem, so I'd also be happy with some waypointers - where to look to find the problem. Moving from the original 32-bit version of mulacc (as in the link) to the 64-bit (with UMULL) worked fine, but somehow changing to this UMLAL instruction did not as expected.

Comment: @M.P.: I would suggest to add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - no linker script, but a set of .c, .h, .s, .S, .inc files that would compile, implementing both multiplication schemes .  This would help a lot helping you. Providing the expected `bigint_t` result  in the C code would help as well. This would be enough for us to run your code on an M33 platform or QEMU.

Comment: I added the .S file and a minimal .c file for calling it with the values. I could compile it (with the call mentioned) but fortunately can't simulate it or flash to my ARM M-33 target as-is.

Comment: Are you getting this warning when compiling, at the lines where sumA is being used ? `Warning: this instruction will write back the base register` ? I am using using gcc 9.2.1 / as 2.33.1.

Comment: I think using macros make very difficult investigating what is going wrong: 1) This should be done later at the time you will be sure your two implementations are functionally equivalent  - this probably is premature optimization at this stage 2) I would suggest writing two functions - no macros - for each implementation. They  could be named, say,  `mulacc_umlal()` and  `mulacc_umull() `, would have the exact same signatures, and would be compliant with the ARM 32 bit calling conventions.  This would allow to easily capture the parameters and the results for each call of both implementations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220765/discussion-between-frant-and-m-p).